# Change the default screen brightness

Tags: xubuntu, brightness

I'm using   Xubuntu 14.04  with linux 3.13.0-24

Every time my screen goes dark (activating the screen saver or so)
my current screen brightness is set to some default value.

How can I change this default value ? Is it hardware specific ?

Answer (score 1):

Setting

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor”
```

in `/etc/default/grub` (and then running `sudo update-grub`) worked.